Race condition with django GET
I wrote a function in Django which looks roughly like this:
@login_required
def make_appointment(request):
    existing_appointments = Appointment.objects.all()
    print('existing_appointments = ', len(existing_appointments))
    new_appointment = Appointment()
    new_appointment.save()
    # ...

And I call this from javascript using the following code:
for(i=0; i<2; i++){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', "make_appointment/")
    xhr.send();
}

I would expect that the GET command is called first, which in turn causes Django to execute the make_appointment function. The log I would expect is:
[18/Dec/2024 17:42:48] "GET /make_appointment/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
existing_appointments =  0
[18/Dec/2024 17:42:48] "GET /make_appointment/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
existing_appointments =  1

But the log that I usually get is:
existing_appointments =  0
existing_appointments =  0
[18/Dec/2024 17:42:48] "GET /make_appointment/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Dec/2024 17:42:48] "GET /make_appointment/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

But I also already got
existing_appointments =  0
existing_appointments =  1
[18/Dec/2024 17:42:48] "GET /make_appointment/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Dec/2024 17:42:48] "GET /make_appointment/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0

For me, this is problematic because the time of the second appointment depends on the existance of the first appointment so they should be created subsequently.
How can I fix this code?

The default for xhr.open('GET', "make_appointment/") is asynchronous, so there's no guarantee that xhr.send(); will fire after xhr.open();.  You can make it synchronous by doing  xhr.open('GET', "make_appointment/", false), but this is not recommended since it will cause the code to hang.  There are better ways to handle asynchronous code (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest_API/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests).

thanks, I think this answers my question.
